# Program abruptly shutting off Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, multithreading, opencv, raspberry-pi, computer-vision

so I have a Python program on my Raspberry Pi running on an infinite while loop that takes an image from the camera every second.

With every iteration, the program creates a thread which uses the image to process. This process consists of: a script extracts a phone screen out of the image using OpenCV and another script to extract a QR code out of that screen.

I used the program to use pre-taken images to process them without problem but it only chokes if I put the program through a continuous loop.

After a few iterations of the loop and trying to process the images, the program unexpectedly breaks and my Raspberry Pi abruptly shuts off. Does anyone know why this is happening?

I have been looking around for an answer but my suspicions are with the threads. Either, I'm overloading the CPU or RAM, there are memory leaks, the Raspberry Pi is using too much power

**EDIT:**

From the comments below it seems that the power supply to the Pi seems to be the problem. I'm currently running on a phone charger (5.0v, 1.0A) which is (very) below the 5.0v, 2.5A recommended power supply, darn me. I will update this post when I get a new power supply and test the code out.

Also, running the program on my Windows laptop poses no problems at all.

This is my main script:

```
import picamera
import threading
import time
from processing.qr import get_qr_code
from processing.scan import scan_image

# Thread method
def extract_code(file):

    print 'Thread for: ' + file

    # Scans image to extract phone screen from image and then gets QR code from it
    scan_image(file)
    get_qr_code(file)

    return
# End methods

camera = picamera.PiCamera()

while True:

    time.sleep(1)

    # Make epoch time as file name
    time_epoch = str(int(time.time()))
    image_path = "images/" + time_epoch + ".jpg"

    print "Taking photo: " + str(image_path)

    camera.capture(image_path)

    # Create thread to start processing image
    t = threading.Thread(target=extract_code, args=[time_epoch])
    t.start()
```

Below is the script to scan image (scan.py)
In a nutshell, it takes an image, blurs it, finds edges and draws contours, checks to see if there's a rectangle (e.g a phone screen) and transforms and warps it into a new image with only the phone screen.

```
from transform import four_point_transform
import imutils
import numpy as np
import argparse
import cv2
import os

def scan_image(file):

    images_dir = "images/"
    scans_dir = "scans/"
    input_file = images_dir + file + ".jpg"

    print "Scanning image: " + input_file

    # load the image and compute the ratio of the old height
    # to the new height, clone it, and resize it
    image = cv2.imread(input_file)
    ratio = image.shape[0] / 500.0
    orig = image.copy()
    image = imutils.resize(image, height = 500)

    # convert the image to grayscale, blur it, and find edges
    # in the image
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0)
    edged = cv2.Canny(gray, 75, 200)

    # show the original image and the edge detected image
    print "STEP 1: Edge Detection"

    # find the contours in the edged image, keeping only the
    # largest ones, and initialize the screen contour
    _, cnts, _ = cv2.findContours(edged.copy(), cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    cnts = sorted(cnts, key = cv2.contourArea, reverse = True)[:5]

    screenCnt = 0

    # loop over the contours
    for c in cnts:
        # approximate the contour
        peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
        approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.02 * peri, True)

    # if our approximated contour has four points, then we
    # can assume that we have found our screen
    if len(approx) == 4:
        screenCnt = approx
        break

    # show the contour (outline) of the piece of paper
    print "STEP 2: Find contours of paper"

    # if screenCnt > 0 :
    #   cv2.drawContours(image, [screenCnt], -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)

    # apply the four point transform to obtain a top-down
    # view of the original image

    if screenCnt > 0:
        warped = four_point_transform(orig, screenCnt.reshape(4, 2) * ratio)

        print "STEP 3: Apply perspective transform"

        output = scans_dir + file + "-result.png"

        if not os.path.exists(scans_dir):
            os.makedirs(scans_dir)

        cv2.imwrite(output, imutils.resize(warped, height = 650))

    else:
        print "No screen detected"
```

This is the code to scan a QR code out of the image:

```
import os
from time import sleep

def get_qr_code(image_name):

    scans_dir = "scans/"
    codes_dir = "codes/"

    input_scan_path = scans_dir + image_name + "-result.png"
    output_qr_path = codes_dir + image_name + "-result.txt"

    if not os.path.exists(codes_dir):
        os.makedirs(codes_dir)

    if os.path.exists(input_scan_path):

        os.system("zbarimg -q " + input_scan_path + " > " + output_qr_path)

    if os.path.exists(output_qr_path):

        strqrcode = open(output_qr_path, 'r').read()

        # print strqrcode
        print "Results for " + image_name + ": " + strqrcode

    else:
        print "File does not exist"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> After a few iterations of the loop and trying to process the images, the program unexpectedly breaks and my Raspberry Pi abruptly shuts off. Does anyone know why this is happening?

I had a similar experience. My program (C++) realtime processing camera frames unexpectedly crashed. Sometimes with segmentation error inside the OS code, sometimes just shutting off the whole board. Sometimes the program executable file just become zero bytes.

I taken long time looking for memory leaks or CPU peaks or other kind of programming error. Suddenly I realised that my power supply was not so strong. I changed to a new one more robust and I got no more problems.

See in this [link](https://www.raspberrypi.org/help/faqs/#powerReqs) the 2.5 A recommendation and check if your UPS actually meets this requirement.

Comment: Yes, this may be my problem (stupid me). My Pi is running on a **5.0v, 1.0A** power supply from a phone charger. I have also been getting zero bytes in my python file after my turning my board back on so I had to clone the repo again. I will change my power supply and edit this post with the results. Thanks Doleron

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. Sometimes it is hard to find a real 2.5 A. If it is your case, you could use any cheapest step down regulator like the LM 2596 and a 12v power supply which can provide up to 3 Amp regulated 5 V power source https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/174446/using-12v-to-supply-a-raspberry-pi-with-a-switching-regulator

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the answer you are looking for, but using Python with OpenCV on an embedded system is not really a good idea. I have experienced a lot of problems when using python on embedded systems (even with the powerful hardware that the rasp provides you).

All the performance problems I experienced vanished when I used C++ instead of Python. OpenCV on C++ is pretty solid and I highly recommend you to give it a try.

Comment: I'll try to run your code anyway. I currently don't have a raspberry Pi to try it, but I'll take a look at this as soon as I can.

Comment: Okay thank you Mathias for the heads up! I'm going to try to adapt this to Windows and see how I get on

Comment: Yes I've adapted my program to work on my Windows machine and it is working without any problem. I think the problem is with my power supply as appointed by @Doleron. I'm currently running the Pi on a phone charger (5.0v, 1,0A) so I think changing my power supply may solve this problem. Thanks for you help though.